# Syncing north arrow with polygon centerpoint

Tags: qgis, atlas, north-arrow

I am using the QGIS 3.2.1 atlas functionality to create a series of maps. The maps are of polygons from 60 degrees north to 78 degrees north. The north arrow seem to be aligned based on its position within the map.

I am looking for a way to connect the arrov direction with the respective polygon presented on the actual atlas plate. I would probably need a fuction which creates a value for the offset based on a calculated longitudal senterpoint.

Is this possible? If so - is there code available?